# Year and Month columns issue SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, powerbi-desktop

I have received a set of data similar that can be see below. As you can see months are in own column and year in own which are then storing the monthly sale data from the product. To fetch the data I am using Oracle.

My issue is now that as the sale values are listed under month columns it is hard process the data further, for instance in PowerBi. My goal is to change structure as in the bottom table. Currently I don't know how it would work. Any tips are welcome.

| Product | Year | Jan | Feb | March | April | May | June | July | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bike | 2020 | 12 | 42 | 42 | 42 | 20 | 20 | 12 | 10 | 15 | 3 | 16 | 27 |
| Bike | 2021 | 10 | 11 | 15 | 53 | 30 | 20 | 10 | 10 |  |  |  |  |

Goal:

| Product | Sale | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bike | 12 | 2020 | Jan |
| Bike | 42 | 2020 | Feb |
| Bike | 42 | 2021 | Jan |
| Bike | 42 | 2021 | Feb |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.product, t.year, x.month, x.sale
from t cross join lateral
     (select 'Jan' as month, t.jan as sale from dual union all
      select 'Feb' as month, t.feb as sale from dual union all
      select 'Mar' as month, t.Mar as sale from dual union all
      select 'Apr' as month, t.Apr as sale from dual union all
      select 'May' as month, t.May as sale from dual union all
      select 'Jun' as month, t.Jun as sale from dual union all
      select 'Jul' as month, t.Jul as sale from dual union all
      select 'Aug' as month, t.Aug as sale from dual union all
      select 'Sep' as month, t.Sep as sale from dual union all
      select 'Oct' as month, t.Oct as sale from dual union all
      select 'Nov' as month, t.Nov as sale from dual union all
      select 'Dec' as month, t.dec as sale from dual
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=013e1ad55fea2e35ac46abdae02fd67f) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. All the columns is coming from the the same table originally. (Product, Sale, Year, all the month names). This way I could not use this lateral join clause.

Comment: @Meettu Yes you can :) Gordon's solution only uses one table `T` (substitute your own table and try it).

Comment: @Meettu . . . Of course you can.  Did you try this?

Comment: Hello! Yes I did tried but it didn't work first. I will look on back it again. Now I also understand your code better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use buldin function to unpivot column.

Go to Transformation, select column that you want to unpivot, and use "unpivot Columns"

[image]

Output:

[image]

here advanced code for excel (contains your sample data)

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Mers\Downloads\pbi_tst.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Product", type text}, {"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Jan", Int64.Type}, {"Feb", Int64.Type}, {"March", Int64.Type}, {"April", Int64.Type}, {"May", Int64.Type}, {"June", Int64.Type}, {"July", Int64.Type}, {"Aug", Int64.Type}, {"Sep", Int64.Type}, {"Oct", Int64.Type}, {"Nov", Int64.Type}, {"Dec", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Product", "Year"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Columns"
```

this part is doing job:

```
  #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Product", "Year"}, "Attribute", "Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called an unpivot.

Test data:

```
create table sales (product, year, jan, feb, march, april, may, june, july, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
as
select 'Bike', 2020, 12, 42, 42, 42, 20, 20, 12, 10, 15, 3, 16, 27 from dual union all
select 'Bike', 2021, 10, 11, 15, 53, 30, 20, 10, 10, null, null, null, null from dual;
```

Query:

```
select *
from   sales s
unpivot (month
         for total in
         (jan, feb, march, april, may, june, july, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
        )
order by product, year;
```

```
PRODUCT       YEAR TOTAL      MONTH
------- ---------- ----- ----------
Bike          2020 JAN           12
Bike          2020 FEB           42
Bike          2020 DEC           27
Bike          2020 NOV           16
Bike          2020 OCT            3
Bike          2020 SEP           15
Bike          2020 AUG           10
Bike          2020 JULY          12
Bike          2020 JUNE          20
Bike          2020 MARCH         42
Bike          2020 APRIL         42
Bike          2020 MAY           20
Bike          2021 APRIL         53
Bike          2021 MARCH         15
Bike          2021 FEB           11
Bike          2021 JAN           10
Bike          2021 JULY          10
Bike          2021 JUNE          20
Bike          2021 MAY           30
Bike          2021 AUG           10
```

The tricky part is ordering the months in calendar order, as they are named inconsistently ('Jan', 'Feb', but then 'March', 'April'). You could either fiddle with `to_date` and `substr`, or else use a `case` expression to assign each one a number.

Also, how should it handle the months with null values?